# C++ Builder - Problem with TShape component

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-6

I have this piece of code:

```
TShape* T[256];

/* Other code ... */

for (int i = 255; i > 0; i--) {
     T[i]->Brush->Color = T[i - 1]->Brush->Color;
     T[i]->Pen->Color = T[i - 1]->Pen->Color;
};
```

The cycle is executed by a TTimer each 100 milliseconds and the Color of the first TShape change each 100 milliseconds.

During this cycle, I see a blinking white horizontal lines, because before receiving the color of the other TShape, each TShape is invalidated and becomes white.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?
Maybe, I must override some method?

Answer (score 1):

I think double buffering is the key to your problem. If you are using C++Builder 2009 or newer probably setting property Controls::TWinControl::DoubleBuffered for your current frame will be enough.

Comment: TWinControl has a DoubleBuffered propety in BCB 6.  jszpilewski
is referring to you setting DoubleBuffered=true on whatever Parent control you have placed your TShape objects on.

Comment: With DoubleBuffered = true applied at TForm I have resolved the problem!

Thanks at all!

Comment: Please accept this answer so that others trying to help people by answering unanswered questions do not have to waste time.

Answer (score 0):

TShape invalidates itself every time you change its Brush and Pen properties, so your loop is double-invalidating each TShape.  As a workaround, try temporarily removing the OnChange event handlers that TShape assigns internally, and then Invalidate() the TShape only once after you have finished updating it.  For example:

```
for (int i = 255; i > 0; i--)
{ 
    TNotifyEvent OldBrushChange = T[i]->Brush->OnChange;
    T[i]->Brush->OnChange = NULL;

    TNotifyEvent OldPenChange = T[i]->Pen->OnChange;
    T[i]->Pen->OnChange = NULL;

    T[i]->Brush->Color = T[i - 1]->Brush->Color; 
    T[i]->Pen->Color = T[i - 1]->Pen->Color; 

    T[i]->Brush->OnChange = OldBrushChange;
    T[i]->Pen->OnChange = OldPenChange;
    T[i]->Invalidate();
};
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that, since there is less invalidating occuring.  But whatever.  Another workaround is to simply not call TShape::Invalidate() at all at the end of each loop iteration.  Keep disabling the OnChange events so TShape does not call Invalidate() on itself automaitcally, then call Update() on the parent TForm (or other parent if all the TShape's have a common container) after the loop exits.  That will do a single draw-all operation of the TShapes, rather than drawing while looping.